# Primefaces dialog not shown at "oncomplete" after update on MenuItem

Tags: primefaces, dialog, menuitem, commandbutton

I have this piece of code:

```
<h:body>
  <h:form id="form1">
     <p:menuButton value="#{msgs.settingsMenuButton}">
        <p:menuitem value="#{msgs.accountsMenuItem}" url="#" update=":dlgEdit" oncomplete="_dlgEdit.show()"/>  
      </p:menuButton>  
      <p:commandButton value="Accounts" icon="ui-icon-gear" 
                        update=":dlgEdit"
                        oncomplete="_dlgEdit.show()"/>

   </h:form>

   <p:dialog id="dlgEdit" widgetVar="_dlgEdit" modal="true" closable="true" header="Accounts">  
       <h:form id="frmEdit" >
           <p:panelGrid id="pnlEdit" columns="2">
               <p:outputLabel id="lblName" for="eName" value="Name"/>
               <p:inputText id="eName" value="#{tasksBean.selectedLocation}"/>
           </p:panelGrid>
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>  
</h:body>
```

The dialog is not displayed when the menuItem is selected but it works when the commandButton is pressed. 
The behaviors for both are the same...

Can you support me please?

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, but setting the property appendToBody = true in your p:dialog might help you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
oncomplete="PF('_dlgEdit').show();"
```